How to remove many git files at once?
I have moved a bunch of files into another folder in a git repo and git status shows something like
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    deleted:    file1.ini
    deleted:    file2.ini
    deleted:    stm_1.py
    deleted:    stm_2.py

And I want to remove them together. I can remove each file with
git rm <filename>

but when you have many files that would take a long time. So I tried to use
git rm -r . 

but that gives an error
error: the following files have changes staged in the index:

and I tried
git rm -r -f .

but that removed everything. Is there a command I can use to remove only those files that I see "deleted" in git status?

Have you tried git add -A?

Will try it next time. ...

Does this answer your question? Staging Deleted files

You can use the git add -u command. It stages all the current changes.


Use git status to list the deleted files and then filter out the filenames.

Use xargs to pass those filenames to git rm:
git status --porcelain | awk '/^ D/ {print $2}' | xargs git rm



Explanation:

git status --porcelain provides a simplified and script-friendly output of git status.
awk '/^ D/ {print $2}' filters lines that start with D (indicating a deleted file) and prints the filename (which is the second field).
xargs git rm takes the list of filenames and passes them to git rm to remove them from the index.


There are billions of git commands but not one command to tell git that files have been simply moved? I am not impressed ...

@Alex You are not supposed to move git-tracked files manually. Instead, use git mv for moving, then git will know.

@LokiRagnarok Not really.

Whether you move a file manually or say git mv makes absolutely no difference to what git "knows".

git rm supports the command-vs-paths separator -- (many other commands also support it).
You could:
git rm -- file1.ini file2.ini  stm_1.py stm_2.py

or
git rm -- folder

Having said that, if you moving files around within the repo you should not have to remove them explicitly from the original location. If a file hasn't changed, or changed just a little, git will recognize it was a move and all you need is git add --all, for example.
git add --all will work even if you don't move files but just remove them.
From the official help:

-A
--all
--no-ignore-removal
Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.
If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

